# Changing top bar of iphone screen (where the time and battery shows)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to change the color color of the top bar on an iPhone that shows the battery?

My phone is showing as black text on white background but I wanted to know how to change it to white text on a black background. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setTranslucent:) ])
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Comment: How would I get the black background then?

Comment: by setting navigation bar translucent to NO

Comment: no, in the piece of code i've provided. doesn't it move navigation bar down opening black space above?

Comment: no, it's not. Is this code supposed to go in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ?

Comment: no, it is supposed to be called in your ViewController's viewDidLoad. Do you use navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {

    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

If that doesn't work then change it in your info plist Status Bar Style to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS < 7, you can use any of the below mentioned styles apart from the default ones:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

For iOS 7 follow these steps:

```
1. Set the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES in the plist

2. In viewDidLoad do a [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

3. Add the following method:

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

Comment: Yes. You need to add this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: What this does is it gives me **white text on a white background**. How would I get a black background?

Comment: What is the iOS version you are running on. The above code works for me.

Comment: 7.0.2 -- there are apps on my phone that have the black status background, so I know it's possible...

Comment: Ok. Try by setting iApplication.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque; in your - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)iApplication didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)iLaunchOptions